# how to convert ansi to utf8 in hive

Tags: hive

I want to use custom inputformat in hive, i find the code here:
https://github.com/msukmanowsky/OmnitureDataFileInputFormat
but when i finished the test code i find that the ftp log files which i want to parse in hive  is encoding by "ANSI"("GBK" actually), so the result can't be displayed normally in java console.

So could you help me how to convert the code to make sure the display normally, thanks.
You can make an example in OmnitureDataFileInputFormat. The code is in the address:
https://github.com/msukmanowsky/OmnitureDataFileInputFormat.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The following Generic UDF can be used to convert a field with GBK charset to UTF-8.
This UDF should be used before you have any operation on this field.

```
public class GUDFTestGBK extends GenericUDF{

private StringObjectInspector oi;

@Override
public ObjectInspector initialize(ObjectInspector [] arguments) throws  UDFArgumentException {
    if (arguments.length != 1) {
        throw new UDFArgumentLengthException(
            "The function GUDFTestGBK(s) takes exactly 1 arguments.");
    }

    converter = ObjectInspectorConverters.getConverter(arguments[0],
        PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.writableStringObjectInspector);
    oi = (StringObjectInspector)arguments[0];

    return PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.writableStringObjectInspector;
}


@Override
public Object evaluate(DeferredObject [] arguments) throws HiveException{

    try{
        Text str = oi.getPrimitiveWritableObject(arguments[0].get());
        byte [] bytes = str.getBytes();
        String s = new String(bytes, "GBK");
        Text new_str = new Text(s.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        return new_str;
    } catch (Exception e){
        return new Text("Charset conversion failed.");
    }
}

@Override
public String getDisplayString(String[] children){
    return "GBKToUTF8( " + children[0] + " )";
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i haven't seen the response yet. Do you have the way to match the multiline log informations? 或者我想用正则匹配做日志异常栈处理，把它整体插入一个表字段中，然后输入到文本中。你有什么解决的方法么？跪求，谢谢。

Comment: You should customize a special RecordReader which is responsible for split a file into records. The default RecordReader use '\n' as record separator. So if you want to deal with error stack, you have to implement a more sophisticated logic.